# What does "we make do" mean?

Tags: meaning

I found the following conversation in the Rust (a programming language) subreddit (kind like a forum) at
https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/oymdoj/upcoming_volt_a_rustbased_package_manager_thats/

> A: I released a new tool called volt.
>
> B: A little bit of an unfortunate naming here
> volta: a js toolchain manager in rust
> volt: a (unmaintained?) vim package manager
>
> A: Rust is also a video game. We make do.

What does *we make do* mean here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an idiom that can be found in dictionaries https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-do

Generally it means "manage to survive without something we want"

So A: is saying that they would like a unique name for their projects. But they don't have a unique name. But the project can survive.

Comment: Thank you! I can only accept the answer in 8 minutes. Btw, is this usage common? Have you ever used it in a conversation?

Comment: Yes, it is common.